# jenkins failed to load on java.io.IOException

Tags: jenkins, ioexception

We had installed Jenkins couple of weeks back when we migrated from one server to another, which was working fine. 
We later migrated our jobs with same name like previous job in old jenkins and installed plugins needed. They were also working fine.
Later placed one job’s config.xml and restarted jenkins using safe restart from ui and as a process too.

But jenkins is failing on some 'ERROR Unable to create file nga/logs/nga.log java.io.IOException'. 
We really don't understand where it was trying to write in unix file system. 
We tried completely removing that last job of which we had pasted config.xml and restarted it, even same error. 
On UI it says : Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work…
jenkins version: 2.89.3 
java : 1.8.0_60
Full jenkins logs are below.

```html
Jenkins home directory: /app/jenkins/jenkins_home found at: SystemProperties.getProperty("JENKINS_HOME") 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStart 
INFO: Started w.@2254127a{/,file:///var/cache/jenkins/war/,AVAILABLE}{/var/cache/jenkins/war} 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector doStart 
INFO: Started ServerConnector@5be1d0a4{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080} 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:00 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server doStart 
INFO: Started @1101ms 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:00 PM winstone.Logger logInternal 
INFO: Winstone Servlet Engine v4.0 running: controlPort=disabled 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:01 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained 
INFO: Started initialization 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:01 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained 
INFO: Listed all plugins 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:01 PM hudson.plugins.ansicolor.PluginImpl start 
INFO: AnsiColor: eliminating boring output (https://github.com/jenkinsci/ansicolor-plugin) 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:04 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.PluginImpl start 
INFO: Starting Gerrit-Trigger Plugin 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:04 PM com.sonymobile.tools.gerrit.gerritevents.GerritSendCommandQueue startQueue 
INFO: SendQueue started! Current pool size: 1 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:04 PM ruby.RubyRuntimePlugin start 
INFO: Injecting JRuby into XStream 
2018-02-17 12:53:11,291 pool-6-thread-3 ERROR Unable to create file nga/logs/nga.log java.io.IOException: No such file or directory 
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method) 
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:421) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:403) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551) 
at com.hpe.application.automation.tools.octane.tests.junit.JUnitExtension.<clinit>(JUnitExtension.java:69) 
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) 
at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:669) 
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:366) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:304) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:169) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1096) 
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:82) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:104) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:176) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-02-17 12:53:11,298 pool-6-thread-3 ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:566) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:582) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:217) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:152) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:551) 
at com.hpe.application.automation.tools.octane.tests.junit.JUnitExtension.<clinit>(JUnitExtension.java:69) 
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) 
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) 
at hudson.ExtensionFinder$Sezpoz.scout(ExtensionFinder.java:669) 
at hudson.ClassicPluginStrategy.findComponents(ClassicPluginStrategy.java:476) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.load(ExtensionList.java:366) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.ensureLoaded(ExtensionList.java:304) 
at hudson.ExtensionList.getComponents(ExtensionList.java:169) 
at jenkins.model.Jenkins$6.onInitMilestoneAttained(Jenkins.java:1096) 
at jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1.onAttained(InitReactorRunner.java:82) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorListener$Aggregator.onAttained(ReactorListener.java:104) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$1.run(Reactor.java:176) 
at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:117) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@774e54e] unable to create manager for [nga/logs/nga.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@36770e67[pattern=nga/logs/nga-%i.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=2097152)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=10), advertiseURI=null, layout=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %p - %c{1}: %m%n]] 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:75) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103) 
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191) 
... 35 more
2018-02-17 12:53:11,302 pool-6-thread-3 INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory. 
2018-02-17 12:53:11,332 pool-6-thread-3 ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders. 
2018-02-17 12:53:11,341 pool-6-thread-3 ERROR Unable to locate appender "OctaneFileAppender" for logger config "root" 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained 
INFO: Prepared all plugins 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:16 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.replication.ReplicationCache initialize 
INFO: initialized replication cache with expiration in MINUTES: 360 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:16 PM com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.gerrit.trigger.replication.ReplicationQueueTaskDispatcher <init> 
WARNING: No GerritHandler was specified, won't register as event listener, so no function. 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained 
INFO: Started all plugins 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:17 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error 
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component hudson.plugins.build_timeout.operations.AbortAndRestartOperation$DescriptorImpl; skipping 
Feb 17, 2018 12:53:17 PM hudson.ExtensionFinder$GuiceFinder$FaultTolerantScope$1 error 
INFO: Failed to instantiate optional component org.biouno.unochoice.model.ScriptlerScript$DescriptorImpl; skipping
```

Comment: Happening again with Jenkins LTS 2.150.3.  Did you ever get a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

What resolved this for me with Jenkins 2.150.3 installed was to:

- Uninstall ActiveChoices plugin which is the source of the `org.biouno.unochoice...` in the last line of the log.

Having done that action and restarting Jenkins, the startup log in jenkins.err.log was clean with the last line being `Started all plugins`.

Yet Jenkins was still stuck on the "Jenkins is starting up" screen.

- Uninstall Azure CLI 2.0.59 (at time of writing this is the latest version of Azure CLI).

This fixed it for me. Jenkins login page appeared.

Azure CLI 2.0.59 kills Jenkins 2.150.3!

I suspect unochoice plugin may have nothing to do with it.